# 404 error handling on very simple ASP.Net MVC 4 application without "Home Controller"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

Let's admit I have a very simple MVC.Net application, already deployed (Windows Server 2008 R2). 
I can change its IIS and Web.config settings, but not the application build itself.

The application is a set of service methods, all in the same controller, let's call it "ServiceController".

The route configuration has default content :

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

But there is **no Home controller** defined.

The ServiceController is available exactly as expected, but obviously the root of the website will display a 404 error :

> The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>   Requested URL: /

Now the question : I would like to be able to handle 404, or at least to display a "default" page on the root of the website. Obviously, it would be easier if I could change the application itself.

I tried various approaches :

- **Adding a default.htm** or Default.aspx at the root of the website, but this is overriden by MVC settings and the page is never accessed even if defined in "Default document" section of IIS.
- **Adding a httpErrors section** in system.webServer web.config's section :

  `<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="404.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  </httpErrors>`

But it does nothing. I tried variants with Redirect, and other path forms. Of course I've created 404.htm.

- **Adding in system.web** web.config's section
  `<customErrors mode="On" >
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.html" />
  </customErrors>`

But it fails with the following exception : "The controller for path '/404.html' was not found or does not implement IController."

I have a very far remember of a IIS setting somewhere to tell "handle queries to physical pages if they exist before to apply the route rewriting engine".

*Have you got an idea on how to catch 404 errors in my application, or to add a default page at the root of the website without to change the application build ?* Thanks

Comment: Why not just change the default route (so its `controller = "Service"`)

Comment: Hello @StephenMuecke. As I said I would like to be able to handle 404 or "Default" page without to modify the application sources/build. Obviously it would be far easier if I could ;). I was hoping for a IIS/web.config trick to easily handle this and I was surprised to don't be able to have it working with customErrors and so.

Comment: you can catch the 404 from iis also, change the url associated with 404 from iis and redirect it to your desired destination.

Comment: @Mr.Bhanushali You mean by changing the "%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr\<LANGUAGE-TAG>\404.htm" mapping in "Error pages" of the website ? I would prefer an option based on App.Settings for maintenance purposes but if it works at least it's an option. Thanks for the proposal.

Comment: @AFract I know that's not very efficient way but its an option.